# How to make IAP available on all devices?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

My app provides an in-app purchase to get some news alerts as push notifications. Push notifications should be delivered to all devices associated with the same Apple ID that is used to purchase.

Currently I thought of putting a button on the "settings" screen to restore in-app purchases to check if the feature is purchased in another device.

Is there any better way to handle this task? If so, any tips/suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You need a "restore" button anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restore purchases option is the correct choice, and probably ought to be there in case the user deletes and reinstalls the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `restore purchase` feature:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

It will restore all purchases that the user has made on that account, weather on the same ios device, or a different one.

Also, as a side note, if you implement `In-app purchases` without including the `restore` feature, your ios app will not be accepted by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Or in iOS7, use SKReceiptRefreshRequest.

```
self.refreshRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
self.refreshRequest.delegate = self;
[self.refreshRequest start];
```

Also note that this straightforward restore procedure doesn't necessarily work for all types of products. E.g., at least on iOS6, restoreCompletedTransactions will not restore non-renewable subscriptions. But the situation seems more complicated in iOS7 (see [Non-renewing Subscriptions: Removed From Receipt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913875/ios7-non-renewing-subscriptions-removed-from-receipt)).