# In-app purchase - Receiving multiple products per receipt for a sandbox id

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, in-app-purchase, ios8.1

I know this is a valid scenario, that the iTunes receipt for in-app purchase might contain multiple products.
Just wanted to confirm when can this happen or how do I reciprocate this behaviour for a sandbox id.
Currently its happening on only one of my sandbox user id's. I don't know why but its not happening on any of the other or any new sandbox user id's I created. All of the other id's are receiving a single product per receipt.
This is critical to know because the server side needs to parse this info correctly, so all I need to know is when can this scenario of receiving multiple products per receipt re-occur ?

Thanks

Comment: What type of products do you have? All purchases aside from consumable wll be retained in the receipt for the apple id/app. For >= iOS7. The Apple docs are about to be updated on this point. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913875/ios7-non-renewing-subscriptions-removed-from-receipt I'll update that when apple releases the docs but they finally got back to me on the bug report.

Comment: All of my products are consumable. Yet, some of them are still retained in the receipt.And this happens for only one of my sandbox user ID. Other ID's are having a single product/receipt as expected. Is this a bug in the receipts then?

Comment: I'd file a bug report on this to Apple.